# How to identify crash from XIB

Tags: ios, crash, xib

I don't have any code implemented in view controller to set the font or attributedLabel. But I'm seeing crash with below reason.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: -[_SwiftValue pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x610001040ba0

Comment: check where you use attributed string

Comment: @MikeAlter, I already mentioned. I don't have any code related to setting font or attributed label. And so I don't to use attributed string.

Comment: or any third party library integrated ? , or converted to swfit 3 syntax from older ones may causes problem

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of debugging issue. When app is crashed, check left panel and you will observe threads stack. In that find out **Obj_exception_throw** select that and use your logging area to run command **po $arg1**. This may give you the correct reason for crashing.

Or else, you can try using Application Unit tests for verifying all your IBOutlets and objects, loaded from NIBs.

Answer (score 0):

You can select that xib and open it as source code.
[image]

Or search tho whole project to find that.
[image]

Comment: How can we identify the reason for crash even if we open the xib as src code?

Comment: @Satyam We should find it out firstly.

Comment: My questions is about that. How to find it from XIB?